# Nodemailer greeting never received with own smtp server

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer to send an email, and I’m using a corporate own smtp server.
 The following is my code :

```
Const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
host : smtp.example.com,
Port:25,
Tls: { rejectUnauthorized: false}
});
```

When I try to connect and logged my code, I get a connection established log and a greetings never received error. So connection is closed later. Can anybody help solve this ? TIA.The below is the version of nodemailer : 6.4.2
Node:11.9

Comment: we did not get your point please explain more about you problem

Comment: @prakash Karena : I’m getting a greetings never received error while trying to connect to my own smtp server. The above is my code.

Comment: are you sure about your host and port ?

Comment: @Prakash Karena: Yes, the host is smtp.(my corporate).com

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide smtpTransport as well use nodemailer-smtp-transport npm for that

```
        const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
        var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

        //account from which we have to send email make sure use have allow permisions in account https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps
        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
            auth: {
              user:  "YOUR_USER_NAME", //config.email 
              pass:  "PASSWORD"              //config.pass //password
            }
          }));
```

Comment: you can refer my project https://github.com/karenaprakash/node_mailer.git

Comment: Actually, I am not using gmail. Instead I am using a seperate/own smtp server (provided by my corporate). But even after using the smtp module I am having the “Greetings never made “ error. Is this some handshake problem ? Or something else ? Can u explain that pls?

Comment: are you providing you auth here ?

Comment: like username and password

Comment: That is not required in my case as this is the company’s own server. They are handling it internally .

Comment: i think transporter will check is user is valid or not then it will send mail. if you are using your own server then also your transporter directly not access to send mail  to anybody.

Comment: @apsaradhanasekar were you able to fix your issue? I am getting the same issue as in mine case I have to send an email through company owned server

Answer (score 0):

Add greetingTimeout property in createTransport function

```
//account from which we have to send email make sure use have allow permisions in account https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps
       const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
           service: 'gmail',
           host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
           greetingTimeout : 1000 * (no.of seconds) // try adding greetingTimeout property 
           auth: {
             user:  "YOUR_USER_NAME", //config.email 
             pass:  "PASSWORD"              //config.pass //password
           }
         }));
```